# PHP Script To Check a File Exist in a Remote Server

Tags: php

I want to write a script that checks if the file exists on the remote Server or not.

If file exists `Write` url in a file `found.txt`. How i can Read many urls from a txt file and `Write` the url to a different txt file?

This is my code:

```
<pre>

$sourcePath = "http://www.example.net/file.txt";
$AgetHeaders = @get_headers($sourcePath);
    if (preg_match("|200|", $AgetHeaders[0])) {
        $found = fopen('found.txt', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($found, $sourcePath);
        fclose($found);
    } else {
        echo "Not found!";
    }

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store urls in text file one per line you could manage it like this:

```
$handle = fopen("AddressList.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $sourcePath = $line;
        $AgetHeaders = @get_headers($sourcePath);
        if (preg_match("|200|", $AgetHeaders[0])) {
            $found = fopen('found.txt', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($found, $sourcePath);
            fclose($found);
        } else {
            echo "Not found!";
        }
    }
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: test it but just Get "Not Found" for each url.

Comment: Part responsible for "Not found" is yours :) I only handeled multiaddress search. BTW using @ to hide errors isn't good practice especially when you debug